# AS3 Facebook API JSON.encode compiler error

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

[image: error screenshot]

During compile time JSON.encode error appearing though I've downloaded the latest API, It's a Flash Professional Project.

```
        private function connect(id:String):void {  
          Security.loadPolicyFile("https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/crossdomain.xml");
          Facebook.init(id, initHandler);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is now an intrinsic class in as3, if you're using adobe.com.serialization.JSON you should specify the complete package when using it, like this:

```
com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.encode(object)
```

in stead of

```
JSON.encode(object)
```

See here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html

Answer (score 1):

Either you didn't add **com.adobe.serialization.json** to imports or didn't add as3lib to your project.
Also, if you're trying to build your app with FlexSDK 4.6 then JSON is included in the default package but **encode** was renamed to **stringify** and **decode** was renamed to **parse**

Comment: I've downloaded the complete Facebook api package, that comes with com.adobe.images, come.adobe.serialization.json, facebook.graph.* packages, the serialization json was imported as well, I didn't add as3lib to project, upon search for as3lib, it's directing me to another url, https://code.google.com/p/as3lib/, Please advise further